# Animate a BackgroundImage of a ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So far I have not found any answers to this simple question:

How can I animate a `BackgroundImage`?

```
BackgroundImage = "1.jpg"; // <--- initial

countdown = new System.Timers.Timer();

countdown.Interval = 2000;
countdown.Elapsed += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (BackgroundImage == "1.jpg")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("change background to 2");

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            BackgroundImage = "marcus.jpg";
        });

    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("change background to 1");

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            BackgroundImage = "1.jpg";
        });
    }

};
countdown.Enabled = true;
```

Now I would like to play with this background, instead of changing it I would very much like to mimic what Apple's Photos does with a slideshow:

- **initially** the background is `1.jpg`
- **move** it with an animation in a direction
- **fade** background to `2.jpg`
- rinse and repeat looping images between the two

I don't know, however, how to retrieve the image object so that I can animate it.

Note that I don't want a `gif`, just simple still images.

Comment: Please take a read at the docs. What you're doing is not animations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple

Comment: @Greggz what I am doing now isn't, but what I want is to animate the `BackgroundImage` of a page, not an image inside a page (which I can do easily).

Comment: Assuming you can get the `Image` ref aswell, I'm not seeing much of a difference. Please post the actual code with your attempts to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at `PageRenderer` source code ([see here for Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PageRenderer.cs)), you can easily see, that there is no underlying `Image` like you assumed

```
void UpdateBackgroundImage(Page view)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.BackgroundImage))
        this.SetBackground(Context.GetDrawable(view.BackgroundImage));
}
```

they rather set it direcly in the native control. This means that you'll have to mimic the background image in order to achive animatability (does this word even exist?).

I won't give you ready to use source code, but I achieved something similar with a `Grid` (`AbsoluteLayout` might be possible, too)

- The `Grid` has a single row and column each
- The `Image` containing the background should be added before (within the collection, not necessarily temporary) any other children
- If there is not background `Image`, yet, a new background image will be added directly
- If there is a background image already, the new one is added with `Opacity` equal 0
- Create two animations
- One to fade the old image out
- One to fade the new image in

Code:

```
private void FadeViews(View newView, View currentView)
{
    newView.Opacity = 0;
    Grid.Children.Insert(0, newView);

    newView.Animate("FadeIn", d => newView.Opacity = d, 0, 1);
    newView.Animate("FadeOut", d => currentView.Opacity = d, 1, 0, finished: (_, __) => this.Grid.Children.Remove(currentView));
}
```

Since I am using `TranslateTo` instead of `Animate`, my exact code looks a  bit different, but this should do.